# How and when should I approach management about a revaluation they said they would consider?

Tags: performance-reviews, raise

I had my annual performance review 3 weeks ago.

Management was more than happy with my performance, as I'm doing the job of a seasoned IT project manager but yet hired as a junior business analyst.

I asked for a revaluation of my current salary. Management was less than thrilled but said they would reconsider nevertheless.

3 weeks has passed since the interview and nothing has been communicated to me.

- How should I follow-up on the where about of my request?
- When would be a good time to ask again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: @gnat - I Think this is the followup question to this, of how long do I give my manager to make a good faith effort before I push again?

Comment: *I was hired as a junior but doing the job of a senior manager.* - It is not the managers job to do the work, it is the managers job to assign the tasks to get the work done, and certify that the work has been done correctly.  That is not to say that doing that work is not worthy of greater pay, just that the way you approached it may have diminished its value in  your request.

Comment: hi @IDrinkandIKnowThings, there is the absolute and there are the facts. I got paid for what I'm doing, these are facts. Without quoting anyone, If you are good at something, never do it for free.

Comment: Being paid less than your work is worth is not even in the same ball park as working for free.  As I said its not saying that you do not deserve greater pay, just that the method that you attempted is more likely to harm your case than do good.

Comment: Hi @IDrinkandIKnowThings, what would you have done differently?

Comment: @JohnLegas - see the question linked by gnat for the answer to that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When would be a good time to ask again?

Now is good. 3 weeks is a reasonable amount of time you waited for the manager to update you.

> How should I follow-up on the where about of my request?

Polite and direct is the best. Don't try to beat round the bush or try to put a "diplomatic" spin on your follow-up request. That only wastes everyone's time and confuses people.

> "Dear boss, we had discussed about my salary revaluation a few weeks ago. Has there been any update on the request?

Then take the conversation forward from his response.

Comment: Hi @masked-man, it worked. Let's see how it goes.